# Kendo Ui numeric text box spinner

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, angular9, kendonumerictextbox

I used both methods to display kendo-numerictextbox with spinners but it's showing a normal text box without spinner buttons

```
<kendo-numerictextbox
            [step]="1"
            [value]="5"
        ></kendo-numerictextbox>

<kendo-numerictextbox
            [spinners]="true"
            [step]="1"
            [value]="5"
        ></kendo-numerictextbox>
```

Packages installed

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-inputs @progress/kendo-angular-intl @progress/kendo-angular-l10n @progress/kendo-angular-common @progress/kendo-angular-popup @progress/kendo-drawing
```

and imported

```
 import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you added the css in your angular.json file ?

```
    "styles": [
      {
        "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
      },
```